# Fantasy book about mages, factions and a fighting house

Tags: story-identification, magic

I am looking for a novel in which there are several factions of different mages such as the 'red faction' that has to do with fire and truth.

The main story is about a boy who joins the fighting mage's faction / house. In this house everything is trying to kill you. you have to sleep lightly at night or the shadows attack you, you can't sit too long in the healing pool before little monsters try to kill, if you want to eat you have to fight a man-thing made of leather to prove that you are improving.

The boy's mentor is also a crazy guy who has dolls that help him and talk to him.

Comment: Did the word "faction" actually appear in the novel?

Comment: Are you sure you're not referring to the video game Red Faction? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Faction

Comment: @barrycarter: ... what in his question would match other than "red faction"?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Well, it sounds like a video game, and http://redfaction.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Faction_Wiki seems to be about a world where everything tries to kill you.

Comment: @barrycarter: :) Ah, well Red Faction is a science-fiction story about an uprising of miners against a consortium on Mars. You can see where it's pretty different.

Comment: John, you might look at some of the stories listed at http://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/2038440-looking-for-fantasy-novel-with-protagonists-training-in-academy-theme-t

Comment: The closest thing I could find was the Exiles trilogy, but I don't think that's it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots unless there is another book about miners rising up on Mars, I think you mean Red Rising by Pierce Brown.

Comment: @Dalton:
:) I'm referring to the Red Faction videogames, as is barrycater, I think.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, my bad. You said story, so I thought you meant book. You were talking about the story of the game. Red Rising is part of an awesome new book series I just finished reading. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry this is a bit late, but if you are still looking, you are looking for [The Traveler's Gate Trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/108461-the-traveler-s-gate-trilogy) by Will Wight. I particularly remember the crazy mentor who talks to dolls and the healing bath which will kill you if you stay in too long. The fighting house the main character joins is the House of Blades, which is also the title of the first novel in the trilogy.

Comment: This is 100% the right book series and correct answer as far as what the OP posted about the book

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make a wild guess. *[Blood Song](http://beralshakur.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Song)* by Anthony Ryan which features a man who was deposited at the gates of the Sixth Order and is taught to be a deadly warrior and defender of the faith. The descriptions I've seen indicate that the training is grueling and often deadly. However, his magic isn't learned until later, and is actually anathema to the religious order he trained with. Also, his mentor does not seem to be involved with dolls in any way.

Like I said, wild shot in the dark.